# How to connect phpmyadmin from Android

Tags: android, mysql

I have this website
http://otizmegitimplatformu.esy.es/

we did not improve it yet. It has a database . I can manipulate from this page

http://sql12.hostinger.web.tr/phpmyadmin/index.php?

It is like mysql server or xammp. But for example, when using xammpp, i can connect to database from that url:

`localhost:xxxx/myDB`

for my website, i can connect. Should i use ip address of it? What i want to do is get a row from it. Very basic

Comment: You need to use a URL for your domain host, and conect android using `PHP` files with `JSON` to get data from Android app.

Comment: Cant i connect from asyntask by HTTP client, request methods?

Comment: mmm... `HTTPClient` it's deprecated, now you can use `URLConnection` instead, read about it on Google

Comment: You need to run an API between your android app and your database. If your android app has direct access somebody could just decompile your app and find out your database credentials.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll have to either use the ip of the site (http://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx/myDB or whatever), or the usual online dashboard for this. As the Android device is not hosting the site (as I understand it), localost will not work properly.

Comment: Yes of course, Android device is not hosting.I will get data from there to display.